# Guaranteed unicode or ascii backoff in Python 2.7

Tags: unicode, python-2.7, character-encoding, web-scraping

I'm a big fan of the UnicodeDammit module in BeautifulSoup4, which puts an a string firmly in unicode and also does HTML unescaping :

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
unicode_page = UnicodeDammit(raw_page, [suspected_encodings_if_any]).unicode_markup
```

There are cases where even the mighty Dammit fails, though, and returns an empty string. I want have some kind of backoff into ascii for those cases.

Dammit uses chardet, so no point in backing off to that. (Dammit also looks for the iconv_codec library - anyone have any experience with it?) What's the best way of backing off into ascii? This try loses things, but it also seems to work:

```
def to_unicode_with_ascii_backoff(text):
    if isinstance(text, unicode):
        return text
    else:
        ud = UnicodeDammit(text).unicode_markup
        if ud: 
            return ud
        else:
            return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i) < 128)
```

Comment: Character set detection cannot be done reliably - if by failure you mean those cases, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Added the backoff bit in response to the above comment, with thanks.

Comment: `UnicodeDammit` can use `chardet` internally if it is available. What are the examples of HTML-ism of `UnicodeDammit`? `bytestring.decode(encoding)` is enough to get you Unicode string (no need to encode/decode multiple times). Use `isinstance(s, unicode)` instead of `type(s) is unicode`. It is an error to call `unicodedata.normalize()` with a bytestring.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: edited extensively in response to your comments, with thanks. I misread the Dammit code and thought it would _only_ work on strings that contained HTML entities (what it does do is handle conversions of HTML-ized chars to regular characters _if_ they are present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"best" depends on your application. You could incrementally improve your function:

```
def to_unicode_with_ascii_backoff(text):
    u = UnicodeDammit(text).unicode_markup
    return u if u or not text else text.decode('ascii', 'replace')
```

It always returns Unicode string or raises an error if input is not a bytestring or Unicode string.

Comment: Continued thanks - learned a lot from this. Also discovered [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) for gracefully getting from unicode into ascii when necessary. And ended up needing to remove control characters by adding an `if` to my orig last line to check against `bad_chars = frozenset([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])`

Comment: @CharlesS.: note: 0x7f is also C control character